# Can't hook up new faucet to shut off valve

Tags: plumbing

[image]I am replacing bathroom faucet with American Standardfaucet.  My shut off valve has a tapered connection and will not accept the new faucet connection-threads will not reach.
Is there an adapter or do I have to replace shut off valve

Comment: I _just_ had this problem. In my case, the valve was a "flare"-type connection. I didn't want to install a new flare tube and I couldn't cobble together any sort of adapter from Home Depot components. I ended up replacing the valve.  Maybe someone with more experience will give you a better answer.

Comment: Could be a flair or compression, look at the old pipe if it has a bell shaped flair it is a flair, if it has a straight tube with a small brass or plastic ferrul it is compression both were common in the past, a valve replacement may be needed to work with your newer connectors.

Comment: Take a picture of the valve and with the old line that connected to it, go to the homestore and look at the flexible supply line display. See if there is one  which will connect to your faucet and to the valve.

Comment: Thank all for your responses-will look at flexible lines but was thinking I might need new valves anyway

Comment: I dont know how get a photo to add-- the "tapered" part is the bevel on the male end sticking up from the shutoff valve - the threads from the flexible hose wont catch the threads under the bevel-I guess it is beveled to accept the flared end of the old attachment

Comment: Michael, please make sure you understand [how SE works](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and resolve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That's a flare fitting on your existing valve. You may be able to find an appropriate adapter, but I couldn't dig anything up very easily.

The valve looks to be attached to your supply line with a threaded connection, so it should be fairly simple to replace the whole valve using a new valve with a threaded connection. Shut off house water, unscrew this one, clean the threads and apply new thread sealing tape, screw on the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you cant/don't want to replace the valve you could make an adapter with a short piece of copper tube. Flare it ( need a flare tool.. ) use a flare nut,  then use a compression union or a sweat copper to compression fitting on the other end.

Also if the old copper line is salvageable you could cut it and put a compression union on that.

I don't like cobbling together adapters like that, but on the other hand there is risk of damaging the pipe from the wall if that old valve is stubborn coming off.